# referencing a specific character out of a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I reference only the second character in a column value with data type varchar(200) so that my SELECT * query will pull out only rows for which the second character is a space?

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL-Server?  String functions differ.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Remove the MySQL reference

Comment: `SELECT * FROM x WHERE column LIKE '_ %'`

Comment: `Substring(Fieldname,2,1)` function should give you what you want.

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING` / `SUBSTR` function.

Comment: It's SQL-Server

Answer (score 2):

SQL Wildcard characters are:

- `%`: zero or more characters
- `_`: single character

---

You query should resemble `SELECT * FROM x WHERE column LIKE '_ %'`.

---

`LIKE` is a string operator that compares each character and suggests that your value should *resemble* (loosely defined) what follows.

`'_ %'` means:

- Any single character, followed by
- The space/white space character
- Zero or more of any other character

Answer (score 1):

The operator you are looking for is `like`. Try this:

```
select * from table_name where column_name like '_ %';
```

Here the `_` leaves space for any one character, the second character has to be a `' '` and `%` means anything after that.
Hope this helps.